# How to toggle an image by text, on hover of a button, and delay the reverse toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have the following html where there is a tile which is represented by an image, and there is small "whatsthis" icon below it. I want to show some text in place of the image when the person hovers over icon, and hide it when the person hovers out.

```
<div id="tileImage" class="tile1 tileDiv"></div>
<div id="tileText" class="tileDiv" style="display:none">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac eros vitae nulla tincidunt volutpat. Etiam tortor ante, consequat in laoreet id, bibendum eget libero. Suspendisse vel arcu purus, id laoreet massa. </span>
</div>

<div id="tileContent">
    <span>Something</span>
    <div id="whatsthis"></div>
</div>
```

I have written the following javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#whatsthis").hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find("#tileImage").hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().find("#tileText").show();
    },function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find("#tileText").delay(1000).hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().find("#tileImage").show();
    });
});
```

It is working fine, but there are two things

1. I don't want the text to disappear immediately on hover out, so how to add the delay
2. If the cursor moves from the "whatthis" icon to the description text then I don't want the toggle effect to take place.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't answer your question, but `$(this).parent().parent().find("#tileText")` would be much improved by just using `$('#titleText')` as it uses the native document.getElementBiId and will be much much quicker than your method.

Comment: Actually I can't do `$('#titleText')` directly because there are many similar divs like this contained in `li` and this is content of one `li` if I directly do that wouldn't it apply the even on the first id on the page

Answer (score 2):

Reading from JQuery documentation:

Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; **for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue**.

I've created a little solution... is not the best but have a look on it.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var hideShow = function( el ){
                var titleImageEl;
                var titleTextEl;

                function init(){ ativateListener(); }

                function ativateListener(){
                    $(el).mouseenter(function(){
                        titleImageEl = $(this).parent().parent().find("#tileImage");
                        titleTextEl = $(this).parent().parent().find("#tileText");
                        titleImageEl.hide();
                        titleTextEl.show();
                    });
                    $(el).mouseleave({root: this}, delay);
                }

                function deactivateListener(){
                    $(el).unbind('mouseenter');
                    $(el).unbind('mouseleave');
                }

                function exit(){
                    titleImageEl.show();
                    titleTextEl.hide();
                    ativateListener();
                }

                function delay(){
                    deactivateListener();
                    setTimeout(exit, 1000);
                }

                return {
                    init: init
                }
            };

            $('body #whatsthis').each(function(i) {
                new hideShow($(this)).init();   
            });

        });
```

Comment: The solution that you have given is giving the delay as expected but the problem is that you have statically bound the tileText and tileImage elements, as a result it is showing and hiding text for all such elements on the page, how can we select it dynamically

Comment: I've posted the new solution this should do it, code is not really nice, but I hope that you can use it in some way...

Answer (score 0):

Using onmouseover and onmouse out might work better but here is the fixed up jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#whatsthis").hover(function(){
        $("#tileImage").hide();
        $("#tileText").show();
    },function(){
        setTimeout( function() {
            $("#tileText").hide();
            $("#tileImage").show();
        }, 1000 );
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not working the text is being displayed but it does not disappear